# Magento 2 : Failed to Update Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite Schema when Upgrade

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade m2epro extension with `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, exception occur when command is executed.
[image: The Exception]

I found, exception seems not from m2epro extension because when I disable m2epro, exception is still there.
Does anyone has ideas how to fix it ?

[image: Actually our current catalog_url_rewrite_product_category does not have that problem fk.]
Actually our current catalog_url_rewrite_product_category does not have that problem fk.

Comment: Can you check for **Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite** in **setup_module** table? Is **schema_version** equal at 2.0.0?

Comment: Thanks for your response Jonathan. Yes, its schema_version and data_version are both 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

**1/ Drop index**

`SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
DROP INDEXCAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID ON catalog_url_rewrite_product_category;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;`

**2/ Run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` again**

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Since currently the website is still working fine, I was told to leave the issue there until we have to fix it. But I will keep your solution in mind and hopefully it works! Could you explain how and why this exception happened?

Comment: You welcome! Maybe you have a mistake in your composer.lock as your database has the right version of the module, then your installation thinks it needs to run updaters again.

Comment: We just tried this solution but it doesn't work. We found actually the failure of creating CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID foreign key was occurred in "_catalog_url_rewrite_product_category" instead of "catalog_url_rewrite_product_category", is the table with underscore is a auto backup and will replace the table without underscore after updating successfully?

Comment: We have tried to access catalog_url_rewrite_product_category table and remove existed records  whose fks are not in primary tables.  The exception still occurred. Also we have checked that there is no other constraint using this fk's name.

Comment: Can you drop the FK as suggested in my answer on your test environment please?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your reply! Yes I think my colleague has tried, and he told me it doesn't work. But what I am a little bit confused is you said drop "CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID" (refers to catalog_product_entity) instead of the "CAT_URL_REWRITE_PRD_CTGR_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID" (refers to catalog_category_entity), why? I think the exception happens on the second constraint

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, my colleague have already tried, actually our catalog_url_rewrite_product_category table doesn't have this constraint. I don't understand how does it works without this fk. I have attached the phpmyadmin capture in the "question section".